# Overriding required init with call to super: call can throw but is not marked with `try`

Tags: swift, initialization, swift2

I want to call the superclass init method:

```
required init(dictionary dictionaryValue: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) throws {
        super.init(dictionary: dictionaryValue)
}
```

But I'm getting the error "Call can throw but is not marked with 'try'". How do I wrap this up in a do-catch? Do I need to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just write `try` before `super.init(...)`

```
required init(dictionary dictionaryValue: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) throws {
    try super.init(dictionary: dictionaryValue)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
struct E:ErrorType{}
class B {
    init(b: Bool) throws {
        if b == true {
            throw E()
        }
    }
}
class C:B {
    override init(b: Bool) throws {
        try super.init(b: b)
    }
}

// A)
let c1 = try? C(b: true)  // nil
let c2 = try? C(b: false) // C
c2.dynamicType            // Optional<C>.Type

// B)
do {
    let c = try C(b: true)
} catch {
    print(error) // E()
}
```

or

```
class D:B {
    init?(i: Int) {
        if i == 0 {
            try? super.init(b: false)
        } else {
            try? super.init(b: true)
        }
    }
}
let d1 = D(i: 0) // D?
let d2 = D(i: 1) // nil
```